# Laravel Guzzle HTTP keep returning 404

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm using openlibrary's API to fetch book data. I have problem with some API (not all) which keep return 404, but when i'm using postman to test, it's working fine.

```
$response = Http::get('http://openlibrary.org/search.json', [
'q' => 'Johngreen'
]);
dd($response->body());
```

Comment: `$response->json()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this endpoint with Laravel and I had the same problem but it works on Postman and browser.

The problem is related to the User-Agent of the client. If you don't set it, Openlibrary cannot check the source of the API call (browsers and Postman send the own user agent).

I solved with this code:

```
$guzzle_client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $this->guzzleClient->get("http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=Johngreen", [
    'headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'PUT AN USER AGENT HERE']
]);
        
$response_body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
dd($response_body);
```

Try to use this User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
```

or use another one

Comment: this worked, I used 'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.65.3'. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 2):

openlibrary is not accepting guzzlehttp user agent, try using only curl or a browser user agent.
Both of these works

#### using curl user agent

```
try{
     $response = Http::withHeaders([  
         'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.65.3'
     ])->get('https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=Johngreen');
     dd($response->body());
} catch(\Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException $e){
     // Log your errors
}
```

#### using browser user agent

```
try{
      $response = Http::withHeaders([
          'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'   
      ])->get('https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=Johngreen');
      dd($response->body());
} catch(\Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException $e){
      // Log your errors
}
```

For more info on default user agent used by guzzle, see [docs](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug)

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add user-agent.

Answer (score 1):

Try code below first to view response all content.

```
Http::dd()->get('http://openlibrary.org/search.json', [
  'q' => 'Johngreen'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Guzzle. Try using the below code for consuming API.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://openlibrary.org/search.json', [
    'query' => ['q' => 'Johngreen']
]);
dd(json_decode($response->getBody()));
```